# How to display on-fly-generated image

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I use the following method to create some image.

My question is how I can display it in **.cshtml** page (MVC3)? Which **Razor syntax** I have to use?

```
public FileContentResult DisplayFont()
        {
            int fontSize = 12;

            string fontName = "Arial";

            System.Drawing.Font rectangleFont = new System.Drawing.Font(fontName, fontSize, FontStyle.Bold);

            int height = 150;

            int width = 250;

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            Color backgroundColor = Color.White;

            g.Clear(backgroundColor);

            g.DrawString(fontName, rectangleFont,SystemBrushes.WindowText, new PointF(10, 40));

            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

            bitmap.Save(outputStream,  ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            byte[] byteArray = outputStream.ToArray();  

            g.Dispose();

            bitmap.Dispose(); 

            return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render it using a normal HTML `img` tag, using the URL of your `DisplayFont` action:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("DisplayFont")' />
```